# Replace Multiple New Lines in One New Line

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace multiple Newline characters with one Newline character, multiple spaces with a single space and Insert In to database.
so far I tried this
        `preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n", $text);` and doesn't work !

I also do this job on the $text for formatting.

```
    $text = wordwrap($text,120, '<br/>', true);
    $text = nl2br($text);
```

Comment: You probably should take into account the different possible newline combinations, i.e. `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`. It depends on the system you are running this on.

Comment: what is the difference between each combination ? I am using MAC OS.

Comment: For reference I believe Windows uses `\r\n`, Linux and Unix like systems tend to use `\n` and Mac OS tends to go for `\r`. You should really write your code to take into account all cases though. You should try to aim for platform independence where possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the following pattern:

```
/[\n\r]+/
```

as follows:

```
preg_replace( "/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text );
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably need this:

```
preg_replace("/(\s)+/", "$1", $input_lines);
```

\s --- matches any white space character (all characters like spaces, tabs, new lines, etc)

$1 --- The first white-space char in a set.  If the first is a space and the we have 3 new lines after it. We'll get only 1 space.

Alternatively you can use this:

```
preg_replace("/(\n)+/", "$1", $input_lines);
preg_replace("/( )+/", "$1", $input_lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following:

```
$text = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct end of line character depending on the system. `PHP_EOL` determines the end of line character for you.

`$text = str_replace(PHP_EOL, array("\n", "\r\n", "\r"), $text);`

`<br />` is for HTML only

Windows uses "\r\n" for new line characters

Unix-based uses "\n"

Mac (I think) uses "\r"

Answer (score 1):

Considering the spaces in the last line.
`$text= preg_replace( "/[\r\n]+\s+/", "\r\n", $text );`

Answer (score 0):

try [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
```